# Save list of strings to file

Tags: python-2.7

Is there a really easy way to save a list of strings to a file in Python? The strings should be separated by new lines, and the file is to be read by humans, outside of Python.

Ideally, something as simple as `numpy.savetxt` for numeric arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`pickle.dump`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle.dump):

```
with open('/path/to/file', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(a_list_of_strings, f)
```

To get the list back, use [`pickle.load`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle.load).

**UPDATE** for human readable output, use [`file.writelines`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.writelines).

Assuming there's no newline is contained in the strings:

```
with open('/path/to/file', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines('%s\n' % s for s in a_list_of_strings)
```

Comment: Doesn't work. If I run
`with open('~/Desktop/test', 'w') as f:
    pickle.dump(['a','b'], f)`
the written file contains gibberish: 
`(lp0
S'a'
p1
aS'b'
p2
a.`
The file should be human-readable.